# Google File Picker Export Spredsheet File as xlsx

Tags: next.js, google-drive-api

In my next js application, i'm trying to upload files from google drive using Google File picker api and then upload them to GCP. Apart from google app files (like word, spreadsheet, jam, etc) I'm able to do that.
For spreadsheet file when i try export as application/pdf it works  and i'm able to download the correct pdf formate file from my app. But when i try to export as  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and try to download from the app it download a zip file, not the exact file.

```
 function googleDriveUploadHandler() {
    const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly";
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    const API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

    let accessToken = null;
    let tokenClient = null;

    gapi.load("client:picker", async () => {
      await gapi.client.load(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest",
      );

      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: "",
      });

      tokenClient.callback = async (response) => {
        if (response.error !== undefined) {
          throw response;
        }
        accessToken = response.access_token;

        const view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
          .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
          .setCallback(async (data) => {
            const tokenInfo = gapi.auth.getToken();

            const fetchOptions = {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInfo.access_token}`,
              },
            };

            const files = [];
            const driveFileUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
            data?.docs?.map(async (item, i) => {
           

              switch (item.mimeType) {
                case "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet":
                  console.log("spreadsheet");
                  var exportMimeType =
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

                 const response = await fetch(
                    `${driveFileUrl}/${item.id}/export?mimeType=${exportMimeType}`,
                    fetchOptions,
                  );
                  const spreadsheetBlob = await response.blob();

                  console.log(spreadsheetBlob);

                  files.push({
                    name: item.name,
                    mimeType: exportMimeType,
                    body: spreadsheetBlob,
                  });
                  break;
                default:
                  const fileResponse = await fetch(
                    `${driveFileUrl}/${item.id}?alt=media`,
                    fetchOptions,
                  );
                  const blob = await fileResponse.blob();
                  console.log(blob);

                  files.push({
                    name: item.name,
                    mimeType: item.mimeType,
                    body: blob,
                  });
              }

               if (i === data.docs.length - 1) {
                console.log(files);
                void uploadFromGoogleDrive({
                  files,
                  folderId,
                  ownerId: fileSpaceId,
                });
              }
            });
          })
          .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      };

      if (accessToken === null) {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" });
      } else {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm ready to give any addition information if needed